# Como hacer para que un INPUT solo se acepten algunos caracteres

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como hacer para que un INPUT solo se acepten algunos caracteres.

Por ejemeplo quiero que se acepten los numeros del 0 al 9 y solo algunos caracteres especiales. Si el caracter introducido no esta permitido, que no se marque en el input.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Puedes escuchar el evento onKeyPress o KeyDown del input y en dependencia de la tecla que presione permitir o no que se muestre en el cuadro de texto, o puedes usar el atributo pattern para validar la entrada y customizar el mensaje de error.

Comment: De todas formas puedes aclarar un poco mas tu pregunta y poner fragmentos de codigo de lo que has intentando, para que podamos ayudarte mas.

Answer (score 2):

yo lo haria definiendo una función en el input usando Jquery

```js
    $('.input-number-line').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/g,'');
    });
     $('.input-number-guion-abajo').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9_]/g,'');
    });
    $('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>numeros </p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control input-number" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">
<p>numeros y linea 9-0 y ____</p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control input-number-guion-abajo" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">
<p>numeros y linea 9-0  ----- </p>
<input autofocus="" class="form-control input-number-line" id="coordenaday_mass" maxlength="45" required="required" type="text">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con Daniel, lo mas apropiado es usar los eventos de teclado aunque nos meteremos en problemas por la incomtabilidad de navegadores. 
Solo asegurate de al cargar los eventos a las funciones, leas de forma correcta:

```
function presionaTecla(eventoActivado) {
  var evento = eventoActivado || window.event;
  switch(evento.type) {
    case 'keyPress':
         ...........
      break;
    case 'KeyDown':
         ......
      break;
  }
}
```

Otra cosa mas, no olvides de asignar a tus funciones los eventos ..

Comment: por favor no respondas a preguntas que no muestran el mas mínimo intento, ayudanos a mantener la calidad del sitio